# Access field in nested structs

Tags: go, nested, command-line-interface, slice

I'm having trouble with something that should be simple. I'm working on something that uses codegangsta's excellent `cli` package, but I'm trying to access a property from a nested struct and failing.

As an example, I have:

```
func Something() []cli.Flag {
    return []cli.Flag{
        cli.StringFlag{
            Name: awesome
            Usage: "be awesome"
           },
         cli.StringFlag{
            Name: awesome2
           },
           <etc.>
         }
```

I have a function that takes in the returned `flags []cli.Flag` and tries to print out the string value of `Name` for each member, but I can't seem to access the nested content in the slice. What is the proper way of doing this?

EDIT: Here's what I did, with additions from Mayank's excellent answer

```
func PrintFlagsForDriver(name string) error {

        for driverName := range drivers {
                if name == driverName {
                        driver := drivers[driverName]
                        flags := driver.GetCreateFlags()
                        stringFlag, ok := flags[0].(cli.StringFlag)
                        if ok {
                                fmt.Println(stringFlag.Name)
                        }
                }
        }
        return fmt.Errorf("Driver %s not found", name)
}
```

I'm getting an `index out of range` runtime error now, but I think that's something else I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so we can tweak it to show you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are accessing the value something like this

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "github.com/codegangsta/cli"

func main() {

    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    a := Something()
    fmt.Printf("%T \n", a[0].Name)
}

func Something() []cli.Flag {
    return []cli.Flag{
        cli.StringFlag{
            Name:  "awesome",
            Usage: "be awesome",
        },
        cli.StringFlag{
            Name: "awesome2",
        },
    }
}
```

Which will give you following error

```
./main.go:10: a[0].Name undefined (type cli.Flag has no field or method Name)
```

And the problem with this code is that you are accessing the struct cli.StringFlag values through an interface cli.Flag. You need to type convert this interface to actual struct type.

Hopefully following code will make things clear.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "github.com/codegangsta/cli"

func main() {

    a := Something()
    stringFlag, ok := a[0].(cli.StringFlag)
    if ok {
        fmt.Println(stringFlag.Name)
    }

}

func Something() []cli.Flag {
    return []cli.Flag{
        cli.StringFlag{
            Name:  "awesome",
            Usage: "be awesome",
        },
        cli.StringFlag{
            Name: "awesome2",
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed what I was doing and looking for. This is perfect, and I suspect it was an interface typing issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as you not paste the code reading the `Name` property, I just guess, you need a interface check

```
if stringFlag, ok := flags[0].(cli.StringFlag); ok{
    fmt.Println(stringFlag.Name)
}
```